# Me verifica varias veces un array

Tags: java, eclipse

Seguro que tengo algún error tonto pero no consigo ver que es..

Mi idea es que extraigo un dato de un TxtPanel.
Verifica si ese dato esta en un array. Si está entra dentro del if y hace varias cosas sino saca un mensaje de error.

Pero no sé por que esto me lo hace dos veces.
Podéis ayudarme?

Código es:

```
// Acció button Aceptar
class  BtnAceptar implements ActionListener {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //Creem les variables que utilitzem per registrar usuaris etc.. // Pendent BASE DE DADES
         String usuariExisteix = txtUsuari2.getText(); // la dada que ha introduït l'usuari:                
         String[] usuarisPermesos = new String[] {"administrador", "professor"}; // Array amb usuaris

         // Recorrem l'array per guardar-los a una variable nova. 
         for(int i =0; i<usuarisPermesos.length; i++) {
             String usuari = usuarisPermesos[i];

             //Si l'usuari existeix entrem dins sino avise'm que no el tenim a la BD.
             if(usuari.equalsIgnoreCase(usuariExisteix)){

                // si l'usuari existeix i es professor llavors obra la pantalla professor.
                 if(usuari.equalsIgnoreCase("professor")) {
                     pantalla_professor v2 = new pantalla_professor(); // truquem la pantalla que volem anar
                     v2.setVisible(true); // La fem visible
                     dispose(); // així tanquem la finestra
                 } else {
                     // si l'usuari es administrador llavors obra la pantalla administrador.
                     Pantalla_admin v3 = new Pantalla_admin(); // truquem la pantalla que volem anar
                     v3.setVisible(true); // La fem visible
                     dispose(); // així tanquem la finestra
                 } 
             } else {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el usuario.");
             }
         }      
     }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente... ¿qué es lo que te hace dos veces? ¿llamar al método `actionPerformed`? ¿mostrar un determinado mensaje por pantalla?

Comment: es decir si encuentra el usuario entra en la pantalla pero aparte me muestra el   else {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el usuario.");
                    si pongo mal el usuario entonces lo que hace es que me muestra dos veces el   else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el usuario.");
                     }

Comment: Tienes "Pepe", "Paco", "Miguel" en tu lista de usuarios, y los comparas uno a uno con "Paco". Y *cada vez que el usuario no coincide* lanzas un mensaje indicando que "Paco no está en la lista".

Comment: como hago para no lanzarlo? :S

Comment: Revisa la lógica. Si en la primera iteración lo único que sabes que el primer elemento es "Pepe" y no "Paco"... ¿tiene sentido que avises de que "Paco no está en la lista"?

Comment: entiendo lo que me dices, pero no se como hacer para cortarlo cuando ya encuentre uno.. si lo supiera no preguntaría..

Comment: he añadido breaks; y ya funciona. Dejo el debate por si alguien encuentra una forma mejor de hacerlo.

Comment: Pon dentro del `if(usuari.equalsIgnoreCase(usuariExisteix)){` que tienes dentro del for un `break;`para que deje de ejecutarse el for, pero ponlo al final del if, cuando ya haya comprobado todo.

Justo antes del for pones un boolean encontrado = false; y antes del break que acabas de poner, escribes encontrado = true;

Debajo del for pones un `if (encontrado == false) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe el usuario.");}`

Comment: si si ya lo he hecho. gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalizando un poco, tienes una lista de objetos y quieres comprobar si un objeto dado está en la lista.

El problema actual es que para cada objeto de la lista miras si es el que quieres y si no lo es muestras un mensaje, pero lo que deberías hacer es mirar hasta que encuentres uno que coincida o, si no hay ninguno, llegues al final de la lista:

```
boolean encontrado=false;
for (elemento: listaElementos) {
   if (elemento.equals(elementoComparado)) {
       encontrado=true;
       break; //no buscamos más
   }
}
if (!encontrado) {
  //mostramos mensaje 
}
```

Comment: gracias me gusta mas esta forma!